# Can I use nearest-neighbor scaling with Intel Iris and Windows 10?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, resolution, display

I have been looking into purchasing a 15" MacBook Pro. The problem is that I'm not too fond of Retina display and need to dual-boot Windows and be able to see the resolution without any blur caused by bilinear interpolation. The only solution is through nearest-neighbor scaling from 2880x1800 to 1440x900. Is this possible with Intel Iris, the graphics device listed on Apple's specifications for the MacBook Pro?

Comment: by scaling the screen you don't see the pixels, you see 4 pixels making up what it interprets the one original pixel would be drawing.

Comment: @Tetsujin Right. I edited the question and worded it better. What I mean is that, when the screen is resized, I need nearest-neighbor interpolation instead of bilinear interpolation.

Comment: Is the question about whether you can use nearest-neighbor scaling on Windows on the MBP, or on the Mac, or both?

Comment: @AlanShutko I only need it for Windows on the MBP. I'm guessing it might be an option in the Intel control panel? I've read that it's not possible with nVidia while dual-booting Windows but I haven't found a definitive answer for Intel.